# Test-Connection Return Value

Tags: powershell

So `Test-Connection` with the `-quiet` switch can return a boolean. Now I need to somehow test to see whether that is True or False, then carry out an action dependent on that result. Is that possible? I'm fairly new to Powershell but I assume logic as follows:

```
If {Test-Connection -quiet PCNAME} == TRUE then..
Else...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the syntax is incorrect

```
if (Test-Connection -quiet PCNAME)
{
    # bla bla bla
}
else
{
    # bla bla bla
}
```

Also, powershell doesnt have an `==` operator, instead use `-eq`.

for example `if ($foo -eq 0) { ... }`

Similary:

`-ne` not equals

`-gt` greater than

`-gte` greater than or equal to

`-lt` less than

`-lte` less than or equal to